# Wenzhixin Bootstrap-table with Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, bootstrap-table

I have a table that's populated via knockout JS using bind. I need to add a search and sorter so I'm trying to implement Bootstrap-table but I can't get it to work with Knockout. I've searched the net but can't find any relevant information. Below is what I'm currently doing, any help will be appreciated.

Knockout

```
    function Sales(Sales) {
        this.Name = ko.observable(Sales.NAME);
        this.Phone = ko.observable(Sales.PHONE);
        this.Email = ko.observable(Sales.EMAIL);
        this.Item = ko.observable(Sales.ITEM);
        this.Description = ko.observable(Sales.DESCRIPTION);
        this.SaleId = ko.observable(Sales.SALE_ID);

     }

    var indexVM = new indexVM();
    $('#SaleitemTable').bootstrapTable({});
    ko.applyBindings(indexVM);
```

Table

```
    <table id="SaleitemTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped " 
       data-search="true"
       data-sort-name="name" 
       data-sort-order="asc">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th style="width:180px">ITEM DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">SELLER NAME</th>
        <th>SELLER PHONE</th>
        <th>SELLER EMAIL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Sales">
        <tr>
              <td data-bind="text: Item"></td>
              <td data-bind="text: Description></td>
              <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
              <td data-bind="text: Phone"></td>
              <td data-bind="text: Email"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any 3rd party controls to add sorting or searching to knockout.

Bind a table to your array (make sure is observableArray) of rows. When you sort the array it will update the UI to reflect this automatically.

Searching (you probably mean filtering) is a little harder but i would essentially have a text box bound to a search term observable, then have a computedObservable that returns all rows that contain my search term. You can then bind to these 'computed' rows instead.

Answer (score 1):

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RafaelCompanhoni/0c0e37rd/) demonstrates how to integrate a knockout application with the Wenzhixin table using sorting and searching via a custom binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

In the fiddle, there's a custom binding called 'bootstrapTable' which can be used like so:

```
<table id="SaleitemTable" data-bind="bootstrapTable: { source: Sales }"></table>
```

The only parameter in this binding is the observableArray that will be used as the the table 'source'. In the custom binding implementation the configuration object used to initialize the table is created. The resulting config object will be something like:

```
{
    columns: [
        { field: "Name", title: "Name", sortable: true}
        { field: "Phone", title: "Phone", sortable: true}
        ...
    ],

    data: [
       { Name: "Mary", Phone: "123" },
       { Name: "John", Phone: "456" } 
    ]
}
```

To enable search (or any other option described in the Wenzhixin table [docs](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)) just add the 'search' property in the config object:

```
var config = {
      columns: columns,
      data: data,
      search: true
};
$(element).bootstrapTable(config);
```

The custom binding in the snippet should serve as an initial draft from where you can expand upon. For instance right now the custom binding is making every column 'sortable' but you could change that according to your needs.